# How can I increase the font size for all programs without changing the resolution on OS X El Capitan?

Tags: macos, font, accessibility

I wonder how I can increase the font size for all programs without changing the resolution on OS X El Capitan. I don't want to change the resolution:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method of increasing the font size globally. (Older methods, such as those provided by TinkerTool no longer work.)

However, there are settings to make various parts of the interface larger. The Finder text can be made larger in Finder's View Options. (The Finder Sidebar text can be set in System Settings > Appearance.) Text in Mail.app can be configured in its preferences, etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html) does work with macOS 13.5.
It provides some font size customization system wide.
A few areas however can not be customized.
[image: TinkerTool fonts]

Comment: There is also a way to make the text in the menu bar a little larger : 
System Settings > Accessibility > Display > Menu bar size : Large